# Duplicate Fields using itextsharp

Tags: itext, adobe, acrobat

I have this code to create TextFields

```
public void MssCreateTextField(byte[] ssPdf, RCRectangleRecord ssRectangle, string ssName, int ssFontSize, string ssValue, int ssPage, out byte[] ssPdfOut, bool ssIsMultiline) {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ssPdf);
        ssPdfOut = null;

        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);

        /*TextField tField = new TextField(stamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle((float)ssRectangle.ssSTRectangle.ssllx, (float)ssRectangle.ssSTRectangle.sslly, (float)ssRectangle.ssSTRectangle.ssurx, (float)ssRectangle.ssSTRectangle.ssury), ssName);




        if (ssValue!="")
            tField.Text = ssValue;

        if (ssIsMultiline)
            tField.Options = TextField.MULTILINE;


         tField.FontSize = ssFontSize;*/

        PdfFormField tField = PdfFormField.CreateTextField(stamper.Writer, ssIsMultiline, false, 50);

        tField.FieldName = ssName;
        tField.SetWidget(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle((float)ssRectangle.ssSTRectangle.ssllx, (float)ssRectangle.ssSTRectangle.sslly, (float)ssRectangle.ssSTRectangle.ssurx, (float)ssRectangle.ssSTRectangle.ssury), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_TOGGLE);



         stamper.FormFlattening = false;
        stamper.AddAnnotation(tField, ssPage);


        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();

        ssPdfOut = output.ToArray();
    }
```

As you can see i have some code commented as an alternative but the two different ways are producing the same result.

What i am trying to achieve is create two textfields with the same name to when editing one it edits the others two. This two codes do that (in the browsers and pdfescape site) excepting in the adobe acrobat reader. In the acrobat reader i get just the first field visible and the others hidden i dont know why...

Comment: I only see your code creating a single text field, not two fields.

Comment: Yes but i call two times the function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add two text field visualizations which represent the same content, you have to add them as **two widgets of the same field** and **not two distinct fields**, e.g. like this:

```
public void CreateDoubleTextField(byte[] ssPdf, Rectangle ssRectangle1, Rectangle ssRectangle2, string ssName, int ssFontSize, string ssValue, int ssPage, out byte[] ssPdfOut, bool ssIsMultiline)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ssPdf);
    ssPdfOut = null;

    var output = new MemoryStream();
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);

    PdfFormField tField = PdfFormField.CreateTextField(stamper.Writer, ssIsMultiline, false, 50);
    tField.FieldName = ssName;

    PdfFormField widget1 = PdfFormField.CreateEmpty(stamper.Writer);
    widget1.SetWidget(ssRectangle1, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_TOGGLE);
    PdfFormField widget2 = PdfFormField.CreateEmpty(stamper.Writer);
    widget2.SetWidget(ssRectangle2, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_TOGGLE);

    tField.AddKid(widget1);
    tField.AddKid(widget2);

    stamper.FormFlattening = false;
    stamper.AddAnnotation(tField, ssPage);

    stamper.Close();
    reader.Close();

    ssPdfOut = output.ToArray();
}
```

(As I don't have that `RCRectangleRecord`, I use the iTextSharp `Rectangle` class as argument.)

This gives you two field visualizations in Adobe Acrobat Reader; after editing one of them and switching focus (e.g. clicking somewhere outside that visualization), the other visualization duplicates the content.

Comment: Where do you use ssRectangle1?
Can i do that with TextField instead of PdfFormField?
And how can i do it in sequence, not all fields in the same method?

Comment: *"Where do you use ssRectangle1?"* - In `widget1.SetWidget(ssRectangle1, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_TOGGLE);`

Comment: *"Can i do that with TextField instead of PdfFormField?"* - `TextField` has been implemented with single-visualization text form fields in mind. Thus: No, not as is. But you can consider extending `Textfield` to a class for multi-visualization text form fields, it is a good base.

Comment: *"And how can i do it in sequence, not all fields in the same method?"* - I'm afraid not quite that easy, at least in iTextSharp 5 you'd have to dig down into the PDF structure and use the iTextSharp lowlevel API.

Comment: Can i do a foreach in acrofields.fields comparing by name and somehow cast to pdfformfield to add the kid?

Comment: @zipzap No. As said above, you cannot use such highlevel iText 5 APIs but instead have to navigate through the PDF dictionaries. If I find some time, I'll try and write some code for that. But this is no trivial task, the iText 5 APIs simply have not been made with that use case in mind...

Answer (score 0):

Now i have this and i can create two fields when the list has more than one Rectangle but for some reason i dont know how the two fields appears without the name!!

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ssPdf);
        ssPdfOut = null;

        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);

        TextField tField;


        if (ssRectangle.Count==1){

            tField= new TextField(stamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle((float)ssRectangle[0].ssSTRectangle.ssllx, (float)ssRectangle[0].ssSTRectangle.sslly, (float)ssRectangle[0].ssSTRectangle.ssurx, (float)ssRectangle[0].ssSTRectangle.ssury), ssName);
            if (ssValue!="")
            tField.Text = ssValue;

            if (ssIsMultiline)
                tField.Options = TextField.MULTILINE;


             tField.FontSize = ssFontSize;

             tField.FieldName = ssName;

             stamper.AddAnnotation(tField.GetTextField(), ssPage);
        }


        else
        {

            PdfFormField PtField = PdfFormField.CreateTextField(stamper.Writer, ssIsMultiline, false, 250);
            PtField.Name=ssName;
            foreach (RCRectangleRecord item in ssRectangle)
                {
                /*
                    tField=new TextField(stamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle((float)ssRectangle[0].ssSTRectangle.ssllx, (float)ssRectangle[0].ssSTRectangle.sslly, (float)ssRectangle[0].ssSTRectangle.ssurx, (float)ssRectangle[0].ssSTRectangle.ssury), ssName);
                    tField.FieldName = ssName;
                    PtField.AddKid(tField.GetTextField());*/

                    PdfFormField widget = PdfFormField.CreateEmpty(stamper.Writer);
                    widget.SetWidget(new Rectangle((float)item.ssSTRectangle.ssllx, (float)item.ssSTRectangle.sslly, (float)item.ssSTRectangle.ssurx, (float)item.ssSTRectangle.ssury), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_TOGGLE);
                    widget.Name = ssName;
                    PtField.AddKid(widget);
                }

            stamper.AddAnnotation(PtField, ssPage);

        }



        stamper.FormFlattening = false;


        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();

        ssPdfOut = output.ToArray();
```

Comment: Got it

PtField.Name=ssName; should be PtField.FieldName=ssName;